# How can I control a RaspiCam with the display CSI?

Tags: pi-3b+, raspicam

I was working with a RaspiCam on my 3B+ when something  in the hardware broke. The Pi does not recognize my cam anymore. But when I connected it to the display CSI the LED 
on the cam started glowing. So now I wonder: Is there any way to control the RaspiCam using the Pi's builtin CSI port for the display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two major problems: the first is, of course, that neither the CSI nor the DSI interfaces are documented openly, so even if it is possible to switch the signal assignments in software (it may not be), you still have to figure out how to do it. The second problem is that the SDA/SCL signals on the connectors are in different places (look at the (partial) schematics: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3bplus_1p0_reduced.pdf), so even if you could overcome the first problem, you would still have to make a custom cable. As fun as all this may be, it's cheaper to just buy a new Pi :)

/ji

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to fix the cam CSI so it works on this port again? Any popular issues with the CSI or something like that?

Comment: you'd need a fairly expensive SMT rework station to desolder the connector and solder a new one, while at the same time not damaging the surrounding components. At some point, it really comes down to "is this worth $35 of your time?". Not even that, really, as the rest of the unit is still working, right?